# ベクトルの欠番を詰めて欠番が無いように要素を置換する方法（R言語）

Tags: r

1,1,2,3,3,3,5,5,7,7,7,7のように欠番があり、かつ各数字の数が異なるベクトルがあった場合に、
1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5のように欠番を詰めて数字が小さい順に要素を書き換える方法がどうしてもわかりません。
お分かりになる方、どうかお助けいただきますようお願いいたします。

ちなみに無理やり書いてみると以下のようになりましたが、とても実用ベースでは使えないような汚いコードです。

```
vec <- c(1,1,2,3,3,3,5,5,7,7,7,7)

# まず同じ数ごとにリストに格納する
testlist <- list()
for (i in vec){
  testlist[[i]] <- vec[vec == i]
}
testlist #  1,2,3,5,7番目の要素に数値、4,6番目にはNULLが入ったリスト

#  NULLの部分を削除して詰める
newlist <- testlist[unique(vec)]
#  リストの各要素の名前を続き番号でリネーム
names(newlist) <- 1:length(newlist) #  リストの要素はvecのまま欠番を保持しているがnamesは続き番号

#  newlistのnamesすなわち続き番号を取り出して、その番地のリスト要素の
#  中身を続き番号と同じになるように書き換える
finallist <- list()
for (i in 1:length(newlist)){
  tmp <- names(newlist)[i]
  finallist[[i]] <- rep(tmp, length(newlist[[i]]))
}
finallist
newvec <- unlist(finallist)
newvec <- as.numeric(newvec)
newvec    # 1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5
```

Comment: match 関数を使うのはどうでしょう。`match(vec, unique(vec))`

Answer (score 1):

こちらで如何でしょうか。役に立てれば幸いです。

```
vec <- c(1,1,2,3,3,3,5,5,7,7,7,7)

target1 <- setdiff(1:max(vec), unique(vec))

for(i in 1:length(target1)){
vec[target1[i]<=vec] <- vec[target1[i]<=vec]-1
}
```

追記
すみません、既にエレガントな回答来てましたね。失礼しました。

Answer (score 1):

`vec`が長いときはこれがよいと思います。

```r
cumsum(tabulate(vec)>0)[vec]
```

Answer (score 0):

1から始まる場合に限定すれば、

```
as.numeric(as.factor(vec))
```

とかどうですかね。