# Pandasで、飛び飛びの列番号を連番にしたい。

Tags: python, pandas

Pandasでデータの処理をしています。  A列がIDで、同じ数字が連続したり 、飛び飛びになっていたりします。
A列の同じ数字はそのまま、飛んでいる数字の隙間を埋めるのに効果的な操作はあれば教えて頂けませんか？

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
1   1   0   0   0   4   1163.7
2   1   0.8 0.8 2.2 0   0
3   1   0.2 0.2 4.4 0   0
4   1   0.8 0.4 0.4 0   0
5   1   0.5 0.7 3.8 0   0
6   2   1   1   8.9 0   0
7   2   1.5 1.5 1.7 0   0
8   2   2   2   8.7 0   0
9   4   3   3   5.  0   0
10  4   4.5 4.5 2.2 0   0
11  4   6.0 6.5 0.8 0   0
12  4   8   8   0.3 0   0
13  4   5.3 0   0   1   116
14  4   0   0   0   4   116
15  13  0.8 0.8 1.1 0   0
16  13  0.2 0.5 3.4 0   0
17  13  0.4 0.8 3.2 0   0
18  13  0.7 0.5 3.0 0   0
19  15  1   1   1.5 0   0
20  15  1.5 1.5 1.7 0   0
21  15  2   2   7.9 0   0
・
・
・
```

以下が目指すデータです

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
1   1   0   0   0   4   1163.7
2   1   0.8 0.8 2.2 0   0
3   1   0.2 0.2 4.4 0   0
4   1   0.8 0.4 0.4 0   0
5   1   0.5 0.7 3.8 0   0
6   2   1   1   8.9 0   0
7   2   1.5 1.5 1.7 0   0
8   2   2   2   8.7 0   0
9   3   3   3   5.  0   0
10  3   4.5 4.5 2.2 0   0
11  3   6.0 6.5 0.8 0   0
12  3   8   8   0.3 0   0
13  3   5.3 0   0   1   116
14  3   0   0   0   4   116
15  4   0.8 0.8 1.1 0   0
16  4   0.2 0.5 3.4 0   0
17  4   0.4 0.8 3.2 0   0
18  4   0.7 0.5 3.0 0   0
19  5   1   1   1.5 0   0
20  5   1.5 1.5 1.7 0   0
21  5   2   2   7.9 0   0
・
・
・
```

Comment: どのような規則でA列の値を変更するのですか？
上側のデータのA列が２から４に飛んでいる部分があります。
目指すデータでは、そこに何かが埋められるのではなく、４が３に書き換えられています。「A列の同じ数字はそのまま」というのであれば、４は４のままになるのではないでしょうか。
何がしたいのかを、詳しく説明してください。

Comment: 上側でのデータは現状のデータで、A列が２から４に飛んでしまっている部分があります。この4を3に変更し、飛び飛びのA列を連番にしたいです。（加えて、上側のデータの13を4に、15を5に変更したいです）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

問題としては [ベクトルの欠番を詰めて欠番が無いように要素を置換する方法(R言語)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/53922/) と同じかと思います。この質問に対する回答に `cumsum()` を使用したものがあり、pandas でも同様に [pandas.DataFrame.cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) を使う事ができます。

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'A': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,13,13,13,13,15,15,15],
  'B': [0,0.8,0.2,0.8,0.5,1,1.5,2,3,4.5,6.0,8,5.3,0,0.8,0.2,0.4,0.7,1,1.5,2],
  'C': [0,0.8,0.2,0.4,0.7,1,1.5,2,3,4.5,6.5,8,0,0,0.8,0.5,0.8,0.5,1,1.5,2],
  'D': [0,2.2,4.4,0.4,3.8,8.9,1.7,8.7,5.0,2.2,0.8,0.3,0,0,1.1,3.4,3.2,3.0,1.5,1.7,7.9],
  'E': [4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  'F': [1163.7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,116,116,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
})

df.A = df.A.ne(df.A.shift()).cumsum()
print(df)

    A    B    C    D  E       F
0   1  0.0  0.0  0.0  4  1163.7
1   1  0.8  0.8  2.2  0     0.0
2   1  0.2  0.2  4.4  0     0.0
3   1  0.8  0.4  0.4  0     0.0
4   1  0.5  0.7  3.8  0     0.0
5   2  1.0  1.0  8.9  0     0.0
6   2  1.5  1.5  1.7  0     0.0
7   2  2.0  2.0  8.7  0     0.0
8   3  3.0  3.0  5.0  0     0.0
9   3  4.5  4.5  2.2  0     0.0
10  3  6.0  6.5  0.8  0     0.0
11  3  8.0  8.0  0.3  0     0.0
12  3  5.3  0.0  0.0  1   116.0
13  3  0.0  0.0  0.0  4   116.0
14  4  0.8  0.8  1.1  0     0.0
15  4  0.2  0.5  3.4  0     0.0
16  4  0.4  0.8  3.2  0     0.0
17  4  0.7  0.5  3.0  0     0.0
18  5  1.0  1.0  1.5  0     0.0
19  5  1.5  1.5  1.7  0     0.0
20  5  2.0  2.0  7.9  0     0.0
```